# Unable to apply fonts in emonbar with fontconfig running Arch

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, fontconfig, suckless-terminal, lemonbar

I am running a new install of Arch linux, trying to set up lemonbar.

I would like to use the JoyPixels font for emoticons, in both lemonbar and my terminal (st).

I've installed fontconfig and lemonbar-xft (which is compatible with fontconfig). When I run `...`, I see `/usr/share/fonts/joypixels/JoyPixels.ttf: JoyPixels:style=Regular`.

My script to run lemonbar looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

. "${HOME}/.cache/wal/colors.sh"

clock() {
        date +%H:%M:%S
}

battery() {
        cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity
}

while true; do
        BAR_INPUT="%{r} $(printf '\uf242') $(battery)% TIME : $(clock) "
        echo -e $BAR_INPUT | lemonbar -f "FreeSans:style=Regular" -f "JoyPixels:style=Regular" -B "#bb000000" -F "$color8" -p
        sleep 1
done
```

I have also tried with the full UTF code: \U000F242, with no success.

I believe the FreeSans font also isn't being used by lemonbar.

If this is helpful, I have been having a similar problem with my terminal, st.  I am using the font2 patch and added FreeSans to the array of fonts, but unicode characters within the expected range don't render on my terminal.

Comment: Try `-f JoyPixels-10` where `10` is the font size.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have worked...